# Regex splitting resulting in an extra space, using \\s but not getting rid of it

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, split

I am trying to parse a string using regex, the string has opening parantheses and ending parantheses, between them small English letters are listed, separated by a comma. Each comma is followed by a space. Like this

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.io.*;

public class StringLetters {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String[] temp = br.readLine().split("\\s*(\\{|,|\\}|\\s)\\s*");

            for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("temp[" + i + "] ===>" + temp[i]);
            }

            Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
            for (String a : temp) {
                set.add(a);
            }

            System.out.println(set.size());
        } catch (IOException ioe) {

        }
    }
}
```

And when I am passing {a, b, c} this as input

```
$ java StringLetters

  {a, b, c}

 temp[0] ===>
 temp[1] ===>a
 temp[2] ===>b
 temp[3] ===>c
 4
```

Other inputs can be {}, {s, h, a, n, o, n, o}, {h, e, a, l, h, t} ... etc

So when I am doing

```
   $ java StringLetters
    {}
    0
```

which is correct, for empty string  I should be getting this 0.

The empty string at the 0th place in the temp array is not what i want, to get rid of that I am using \s inside the '(\{|,|\}|\s)' but that is not helping me here!!

Comment: What is the format you are trying to parse?

Comment: `br.readLine().replaceAll("^\\s*[{},]+\\s*|\\s*[{},]+\\s*$", "").split("\\s*[{},]+\\s*")`

Comment: If you have String like `",a,b"` and you want to split it on `,` what results would you expect to get? Probably `["", "a", "b"]`. Situation here is very similar. If you don't want to have empty string as first result then don't place delimiter at start of the string (try to remove it first before splitting).

Comment: I am passing {a, b, c} as input.

Comment: This can also take {} as an  input.

Comment: Or, `.replaceAll("^[{},\\s]+|[{},\\s]+$", "").split("\\s*[{},]+\\s*")`

Comment: Please kindly post this with an explanation of the regex, I will accept it, if found to be working for me.Please. But for {} I would need a 0 as the answer.

Comment: Still I am waiting for the ways to split it using regex.

Comment: You say you expect to get `0` for a `{}` string, so you can't you `split`. That method always returns at least one element in a list.

Comment: Ohhk!! So its an impossibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need are the single alphabets from the input, I would go with a different approach than splitting.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{Alpha}");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(br.readLine());

        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
            set.add(matcher.group());
        }

        System.out.println(set.size());
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
{a, b, c}
a
b
c
3
```

**Another sample run:**

```
{}
0
```

**Note:** `\p{Alpha}` stands for a single alphabet and can be replaced with `[A-Za-Z]`. Learn more about these patterns [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). You would also like to check [Java regex tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

If you want to stick to your own way of doing it (i.e. splitting the string), you can do it as follows:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String[] temp = br.readLine().split("\\s*(\\{|,|\\}|\\s)\\s*");

        for (int i = 1; i < temp.length; i++) {// Start with index 1
            System.out.println("temp[" + i + "] ===>" + temp[i]);
        }

        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        for (String a : temp) {
            if (!a.isBlank() && !a.isEmpty()) {// Check if the string is not empty or blank
                set.add(a);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(set.size());
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
{a, b, c}
temp[1] ===>a
temp[2] ===>b
temp[3] ===>c
3
```

I've put comments in the code to make it easier for you to notice the changes. The reason why these changes are required is [`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) returns an array with a minimum size of `1` e.g. `System.out.println("Hello".split("$").length)` will print `1`.

Comment: What is the need of \p here?

Comment: `\p` tells Java compiler that it is a pattern. As I have already mentioned, you can use `[A-Za-Z]` instead of `\p{Alpha}`.

Comment: Small nitpick: `[\p{..}]` doesn't need to be placed inside `[..]`. Outer brackets are redundant same way as in case like `[\w]` since both `\w` and `\p{...}` already represent character classes.

Comment: @Pshemo - Thanks for the valuable suggestion as always. I've updated the answer to incorporate the same.

Comment: Please kindly explain the changes you did in the regex to come up with the second approach, I want to understand that.

Comment: @JohnDoe - I've put comments in the code to explain the changes. Feel free to let me know if you need any further explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The regex is seeing the { as the first delimiter, giving you an empty string. The simple way is to filter the array as you create the `Set`:

```
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(); 
        for(String a : temp){
            if (a != null && !a.isEmpty())
               set.add(a);
        }
```

Comment: Yes, { should be a delimiter, which I want to remove. But wht the space is coming!!

Comment: I wanted to ask why the space is coming, I want to get rid of that as well through the regex.

Comment: Split is seeing { , } as delimiters, so you are getting "" "a" "b" "c" "", but the last one is thrown out automatically. Split isn't designed to filter out enclosing brackets or to have starting delimiters that are ignored. You could filter the string beforehand to remove the braces or filter the results after the split.

Answer (score 0):

Without calling the split the above task can be done as follows :-

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.io.*;

public class StringLetters {
  
    public static void main(String[] args){
      
        try{
           
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
          String str = br.readLine();
          Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
          for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
            
              if(str.charAt(i) != '{' && str.charAt(i) != '}' && str.charAt(i) != ' ' && str.charAt(i) != ','){
                 
                 set.add(str.charAt(i));

              }
          }

          System.out.println(set.size());
        
        }catch(IOException ioe){
          ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The task itself is easy but I am interested in the regex, would like to know how this can be done using regex.